# Java highlighting and selecting input

Tags: java, console, highlighting

I've started writing a game in java similar to a weapons shop. I'm trying to have the user have the ability to select items printed in a HashMap within the console. Once the user selects and highlights the item, the user would've bought that item. Is there a built in utility Java has that supports this? Here's what I have:

```
public static int purchaseMedicine(int goldAmount) {

    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("Jewel of Open", 500);
    map.put("Potion", 800);
    map.put("Hi-Potion", 2000);
    map.put("Elixir", 8000);
    map.put("Manna Prism", 4000);
    map.put("Antivenom", 200);
    map.put("Hammer", 200);
    map.put("Library Card", 500);

    int index = 0;

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {

        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    }

    System.out.printf("\n\tGold %d\n\n", goldAmount);
    return index; // Returns the instances of medicineList
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Built into Java the answer is no.

Usable from standard Java, one can try [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) from say `System.out.println()` statements, but these could be mangled by the OS console you are using.

The best solution, if you are willing to import one tiny jar file, is [Jansi](http://jansi.fusesource.org/).  Here, the programmer has better control over what appears in the console.  So basically the code can look something like this:

```
System.out.println( ansi().eraseScreen().fg(RED).a("Hello").fg.(GREEN).a(" World").reset() )
```

You just need to put in the logical check yourself to see if the item has already been bought.